# Recursive :include in Rails ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Say I have these models

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :project
    belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments
end
```

So that I can do

```
p = Project.find(1, :include => :comments)
p.comments.collect(&:user).collect(&:name) # this executes select for each user
```

How do I say I want to also include comment's user?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe `:include => {:comments => :user}` should work.

Comment: What if I am already including something which isn't recursive ?
I currently have :include => :items, and I need to combine it with something like this, :include => { :other_item => :items }.
Is it possible ?